# What is the meaning of following hardware requirement "Encoder Server Lease – High Def capable."

Tags: video, encoding, video-streaming, video-encoding

Could somebody please elaborate what is the meaning of the following hardware requirement
  "Encoder Server Lease – High Def capable."

Does this mean that a server should be capable enough to encode videos to various formats?

Or a server which can access some service from 3rd party to encode videos can be termed as Encoder Server.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: No.  the sentence makes no sense without context. Because HD is a marketing term, not a technical term. Where are you reading this?

Comment: Hello szatmary, sry for the copnfusion my statement might have caused, The context is encoding videos, where the server should be capable of endoing vidoes.

Comment: Every computer ever can encode video. An intel 286 can encode video. Even HD, it would just take a while.